# Rebus service bus. How to map different types/interfaces

Tags: rebus

I haven't found a solution how to consume other interface then published.

In simple case if I want to publish IMessage and consume IMessage I have to share assembly with IMessage definition between two applications.

But what if this two applications are developing by different companies.

In this case I have two options:

1. make an agreement about common interfaces, naming conventions etc and share a common library
2. let both companies do there job as they are used to do and inside service bus (or application server) map data types.

Second option is more appropriate for me, but I haven't found a solution.

For example, I might have an employee in one system as

```
public interface IEmployee
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And in other system as

```
public interface ILightEmployee
{
    int id { get; set; }
    string full_name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to publish IEmployee and consume ILightEmployee.

During serialization/deserialization phase in service bus I want to
use some mapping of properties and archive something like this (it is more like a pseudo code):

```
public class ContractMapper
{
    public LightEmployee Map(IEmployee employee)
    {
        return new LightEmployee()
        {
            id = employee.ID,
            full_name = employee.LastName + " " + employee.FirstName
        };
    }
}
```

For example MuleESB provides an editor for this transformations/mapping. [LINK](http://blogs.mulesoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/handshake-to-quickbooks1-1024x607.png)

It is unnecessary advanced solution for me, but at least in code I want do to the same thing.

Is it possible using Rebus service bus?

Answer (score 0):

As long as Rebus is able to properly deserialize the incoming JSON object into a concrete class, it will attempt to dispatch the message to all polymorphically compatible handlers.

With the default Newtonsoft JSON.NET and the [Jil-based JSON serializer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rebus.Jil/), the `rbs2-content-type` header will be set to `application/json;charset=utf-8`, and as long as an incoming message's header starts with `application/json` and has a compatible encoding, both serializers will try to deserialize to the type specified by the `rbs2-msg-type` header.

So, if you have a matching concrete class available in the app domain, you can have a handler that implements `IHandleMessages<IEmployee>` or `IHandleMessages<ILightEmployee>` - or `IHandleMessages<object>` for that matter, because that handler is polymorphically compatible with all incoming messages.

The Jil serializer is special though, in that it will deserialize to a `dynamic` if the cannot find the .NET type that it was supposed to deserialize into.

This means that this handler:

```
public class HandlesEverything : IHandleMessages<object>
{
    public async Task Handle(dynamic message)
    {
         // .... woohoo!
    }
}
```

coupled with the Jil serializer will be able to handle all messages, dynamically, picking out whichever pieces it is interested in.

I hope the answer gives an impression of some of the possibilities with Rebus. Please tell me more if there's a scenario that you feel is not somehow covered well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm new with Rebus, so up to now it is not crystal clear for me, but good news is that it looks like the Rebus can handle this issue. I have to spend more time playing with it to figure out exact solution.